# Failed to resolve: com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a splash screen which is animated, but facing an error (in title) while syncing the project.
Code in gradleFile is:

```
    allprojects {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
           }
    }
```

Dependencies are as follows:

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
        core:2.2.2', {
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support 
           annotations'
         })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.github.VikaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
        }
```

Comment: off-topic: I would not recommend using this library since it's really old.

Answer (score 1):

you have:

```
compile 'com.github.VikaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
```

instead of :

```
compile 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
```

notice Vi**kaa**Skool instead of Vi**ksaa**Skool

[also, consider using implementation instead of compile, as it will be deprecated soon](http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html)

Comment: But your given link is not working for updated material